# How to add Layer stored as variable to mapbox map

Tags: mapbox, geojson

I am working with mapbox.js and I am trying to reset a layer that I removed, but stored in a variable. I have created a map object and attached it to a div and stored it as the variable **map**. I initialize the layers like so

`var myLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);

var secondLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);`

Then I store them in a json object

```
    var geoJsons = {"myLayer": myLayer,
                    "secondLayer": secondLayer
                    };
```

in a function below, I have an onclick function which draws on the data attribute of the object clicked to point to the specific layer in the json object.

```
var layer = $(this).data('layer');
map.removeLayer(geoJsons[layer]);
```

I then try to re-add it on the click of a different button

```
geoJsons[layer] = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);
```

This last bit does not work. My question is, is there a way to re-add the layer to the map by calling it from within this json object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
geoJsons[layer] = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);
```

What you are doing here is overwriting the layerobject stored with a new instance of `L.mapbox.featureLayer`. The stored layer is accessible via `geoJsons[layer]` (Assuming the `layer` variable holds the string `myLayer` or `secondLayer`) you can add it by simply calling it's `addTo` method like so:

```
geoJsons[layer].addTo(map);
//or 
map.addLayer(geoJsons[layer]);
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot!